# Angular 2 RC Optional Routing Parameters

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I tried to implement this route in angular 2 RC

**example:**

```
/search/[:category/][:subcategory/][:brand/][:page/]?limit=15&sort=price
```

How can I do that? I could use query parameters for everything, but the URL is "ugly". Otherwise, there is a method to rewrite the url if I use query parameters? With PHP is much simple, I'm studying angular 2 :)

I tried to do like this in another component but doesn't work and the `name: 'message'` has an error

```
@Routes([
  {path:'/', component: ListMessagesComponent },
  {path:'/:id/', component: MessageComponent, name: 'message'},
  {path:'/:id/:sort/', component: MessageComponent, name: 'message-sorted'}
])
```

**Console log: for /messages/1/desc/** (this doesn't have any sense)

```
   Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
platform-browser.umd.js:971EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: '1'. Available routes: ['/', '/:id/', '/:id/:sort/'].
platform-browser.umd.js:962EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: '1'. Available routes: ['/', '/:id/', '/:id/:sort/'].BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ platform-browser.umd.js:972ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3696(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8951schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6007SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:5996onError @ core.umd.js:6227onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6096ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
platform-browser.umd.js:962STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3698(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8951schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6007SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:5996onError @ core.umd.js:6227onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6096ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
platform-browser.umd.js:962Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: '1'. Available routes: ['/', '/:id/', '/:id/:sort/'].
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:523)
    at zone.js:571
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6066)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:355)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:256)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:474)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:426)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ platform-browser.umd.js:962ExceptionHandler.call @ core.umd.js:3699(anonymous function) @ core.umd.js:8951schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6007SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext @ Subject.ts:154Subject._next @ Subject.ts:144Subject.next @ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:5996onError @ core.umd.js:6227onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6096ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:233_loop_1 @ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. Current segment: '1'. Available routes: ['/', '/:id/', '/:id/:sort/']. ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: BaseException {message: "Cannot match any routes. Current segment: '1'. Available routes: ['/', '/:id/', '/:id/:sort/'].", stack: "Error: Cannot match any routes. Current segment: '…st:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:322:35)"}consoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: '1'. Available routes: ['/', '/:id/', '/:id/:sort/'].(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

The new router currently requires that more specific routes are ordered first and less specific ones ordered last

```
@Routes([
  {path:'/:id/:sort/', component: MessageComponent}
  {path:'/:id/', component: MessageComponent},
  {path:'/', component: ListMessagesComponent },
])
```

`name` doesn't exist anymore in the new router.

I'm not sure routes that only differ in parameters are supported (yet)

```
  {path:'/:id/:sort/', component: MessageComponent}
  {path:'/:id/', component: MessageComponent},
```

Comment: Works only the /message/ url, (path '/)' :(